# Using handleError out of the box in mvc3, problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I trying to do something like that

First, Create a new mvc 3 project in visual studio 2010

Next, Turning on the custom error in the Views\Shared\Web.config

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On"/>
 ...
```

And then, I put the  Tag in the Index ActionResult, Home Controller

```
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller


    <HandleError()> _
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        ViewData("Message") = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!"
        Throw New InvalidOperationException
        Return View()
    End Function

    Function About() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function



End Class
```

Finally run the app, and always show the yellow message error. I review a lot of examples and always indicated that is correct, but doesn't work.

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this in the **main** `~/web.config` file, not the one in `~/Views/Shared/Web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Also ensure that `~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` is present as this will be the rendered view in case of an exception.

And you no longer need to decorate your controller with the `<HandleError()>` attribute as ASP.NET MVC 3 uses a global filter for this.